# How to modify an existing dxf file using ezdxf python package?

Tags: python, autocad, coordinate-systems, cad, dxf

I'm trying to add entites to the modelspace of an existing .dxf file using ezdxf. The location of the inserted entities is completely off from where I expect them to be.

For a circle, I got the location coordinates of an entity using by e.dxf.insert and used this point as the center of a circle. I've used the following code:

```py
import ezdxf
dwg = ezdxf.readfile("drainage.dxf")

msp = dwg.modelspace()
dwg.layers.new(name='MyCircles', dxfattribs={'color': 7})

def encircle_entity(e):
    if e.dxftype()=='INSERT':
        circleCenter = e.dxf.insert
        msp.add_circle(circleCenter, 10, dxfattribs={'layer': 'MyCircles'})
        print("Circle entity added")

washBasins = msp.query('*[layer=="WASH BASINS"]')
for e in washBasins:
    encircle_entity(e)

dwg.saveas('encircle.dxf')
```

Link to drainage.dxf (input) and encircle.dxf (output) files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aIhZiuEdClt0warjPPcKiz4XJ7A7QWf_

This creates a circle, but at an incorrect position.

Where is the origin in the dxf file and the origin that ezdxf uses?
How do I get the correct positions of all entities, especially INSERT, LINES and CIRCLES?
How do I place my entities at the desired positions in an already existing dxf file using ezdxf?
Where are the e.dxf.start and e.dxf.end points of a line with respect to the coordinates?

I think I'm missing something in coordinates here. Kindly explain how the coordinates work.

Comment: You have to show which result you expect, and what ezdxf produces for your input data, also show what coordinates values you use as input data.

Comment: Could you be using WCS points where OCS points are required, or vice versa?

Comment: How do I decipher the meaning of coordinates of a line that e.dxf.start and e.dxf.end return? Where is the origin for this system?

Comment: All entities of the block definition "WB" are drawn at a big distance to the base point. The circles you added, show you the base point of the "WB" block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python version of @LeeMac solution, but ignoring OCS:

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.math import Vector

DXFFILE = 'drainage.dxf'
OUTFILE = 'encircle.dxf'

dwg = ezdxf.readfile(DXFFILE)
msp = dwg.modelspace()
dwg.layers.new(name='MyCircles', dxfattribs={'color': 4})


def get_first_circle_center(block_layout):
    block = block_layout.block
    base_point = Vector(block.dxf.base_point)
    circles = block_layout.query('CIRCLE')
    if len(circles):
        circle = circles[0]  # take first circle
        center = Vector(circle.dxf.center)
        return center - base_point
    else:
        return Vector(0, 0, 0)


# block definition to examine
block_layout = dwg.blocks.get('WB')
offset = get_first_circle_center(block_layout)

for e in msp.query('INSERT[name=="WB"]'):
    scale = e.get_dxf_attrib('xscale', 1)  # assume uniform scaling
    _offset = offset.rotate_deg(e.get_dxf_attrib('rotation', 0)) * scale
    location = e.dxf.insert + _offset

    msp.add_circle(center=location, radius=1, dxfattribs={'layer': 'MyCircles'})

dwg.saveas(OUTFILE)
```

Comment: @LeeMac How do you calculate location of a block that has been mirrored? This solution doesn't work if the block is mirrored and placed in the AutoCAD file. For a block placed through the mirror command, the entity.dxf.insert and entity.dxf.rotation returns a point and rotation that is different than that if the block was placed there by copying and rotating. Kindly help in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

Planar objects, (such as Arcs, Circles, 2D Polylines (`LWPOLYLINEs`), Block References (`INSERTs`), to name a few) are defined relative to the **Object Coordinate System** (OCS) calculated for the plane in which they reside.

This coordinate system has the same origin as the World Coordinate System (WCS), but the X & Y axis vectors are calculated using the [Arbitrary Axis Algorithm](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/arbitrary_axis_algorithm_al_u05_c.htm) for a given extrusion vector or normal to the plane in which the planar object resides.

I can see that your current code is generating Circles at the insertion point coordinates of all Block References (`INSERTs`) residing on the layer `WASH BASINS`.

The insertion point coordinates of each block reference is expressed relative to the **OCS** calculated using the extrusion vector (DXF group `210`) associated with the block reference.

The center point coordinates of a circle are also expressed relative to the **OCS** of the circle, and so, to match the position of the block reference, you will need to supply the `add_circle` method the **extrusion vector of the block reference**, so that both the insertion point coordinates & center coordinates are expressed relative to the **same coordinate system**.

Therefore, the code should become:

```
def encircle_entity(e):
    if e.dxftype()=='INSERT':
        circleCenter = e.dxf.insert
        msp.add_circle(circleCenter, 10, dxfattribs={'layer': 'MyCircles', 'extrusion': e.dxf.extrusion})
        print("Circle entity added")
```

Comment: getting WCS coordinates from OCS: wcs_location = e.ocs().to_wcs(e.dxf.insert)

Comment: Hi Lee! I tried using the code above and it seems to produce the same output as in the case when extrusion isn't passed in dxfattribs. Does anything else also needs to be added?

Comment: The extrusion for the block entities on the layer WASH BASINS is (0, 0, 1)

Comment: @mozman I would have thought that no such conversion would be necessary given that both INSERTs & CIRCLES are defined relative to the OCS.

Comment: @LeeMac: This is a misunderstanding, transformation to WCS is not required, this was just added to show how to get the WCS location, because it is hard to find in the docs.

Comment: @LeeMac Thanks for explaining these concepts so well. Is there a possible way to finding exact positions of individual entities that comprise a block (and not the default base point (= insertion point) of the block)? For example, a WASH BASIN block comprises of multiple entities, one of them being a circle. How can I get the center coordinates of that circle inside the WASH BASIN block so that I can use that center coordinate to draw something?

Comment: @NamanKasliwal You would need to obtain the center of the `CIRCLE` from the block definition (relative to the origin of the block definition [typically 0,0,0 but not necessarily]) and then transform the coordinate using the block scale, rotation, orientation and position, so that the center coordinate is relative to the block insertion point. [Here](http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?101744-Getting-a-point-of-an-entity-inside-a-block-as-WCS-coordinates&p=690875&viewfull=1#post690875) is an **exact** example of what you are looking to do, but written in AutoLISP instead of Python.

Comment: @mozman What do entity.dxf.insert and entity.dxf.rotation represent when the block is placed by mirroring?